# Execute another function after finishing one function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may be a silly question, till now I am using something along the lines of.

```
$scope.selectEvent = function ($index, event, callback) {
    // Do stuff

    setTimeout(function() {
        callback($scope, $http);
    }, 0);
};
```

The problem is I want to call the callback only after I am done with the selectEvent function entirely. The selectEvent function adds stuff to DOM and adds some variables into scope, and my callback draws stuff on the DOM using the variables in the scope. Obviously if the DOM is not updated and the scope variables are not set, the callback without `setTimeout` gives an error.

**UPDATE**

Suppose this is the function which is called on above callback (and this function too callbacks another function).

```
function my_callback($scope, $http, callback) {
    // Don't make an additional post request if it is already there
    if ($scope.dataForCallback === null) {
        $http.post("get_data",
            {vars: $scope.data.vars}).
            success(function (data) {
                $scope.dataForCallback = data;

                setTimeout(function() {
                    callback($scope);
                }, 0);

            });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback($scope);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The dom is always updated immediately, if you're changing `$scope` variables asynchronically there should be a callback for it.

Comment: Right, $http has success, please see the code... Also, when I change DOM, I actually chose a Angular Template, which is build first (dynamic template).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to `setTimeout()`-- or is it the only good way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just call `callback($scope)` without `setTimeout`?

Comment: hard to understand what your intent is, or why you need to pass `$scope` as argument. How are you using this?